# Como puedo hacer para saber que jugador hizo la mayor puntuación con menos intentos con el nombre que introdujo al terminar en un jtxtfield?

Tags: java

Tengo un jtextfield cuando adivinas pone en cuanto intentos lo hiciste y te pide el nombre. En un menubar un menuitem al que tengo que poner la mejor puntuación cuando le haces click y mostrar el nombre del que adivino en menos intentos, pero no sé como hacerlo

[image: Así]

```
intentosrecord = intentos;
```

tengo esa variable que pasa los intentos a intentosrecord y después lo vuelve a 0 por si juega de nuevo y tengo un string nombre global al cual añado el nombre con el boton añadir pero no funciona

```
String nombre = txtusuario.getText();
```

Comment: ya intentaste guardar un mapa ordenado en un archivo para dicho proposito?